# update mysql value based on previous date value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a mysql table with the following structure

```
id  name_id  class_id  currency     date       value  change
1    BILL        A         0     04-01-2013    10.00    0
5    BILL        A         0     04-02-2013     9.90    0
12   FRED        A         0     04-01-2013     8.00    0
13   FRED        B         1     04-02-2013     8.50    0  
22   FRED        B         1     04-03-2013     8.51    0
```

I want to update the `change` column based on the difference between that day's value and the previous date value when the `name_id` , `class_id`  , and `currency` are equal . . . so in this small excerpt only row 2 would be updated to `-0.10`and row 5 to `0.01`.

There are 400,000 rows they all have an auto-incremented id but the ids are not in any kind of order.  There are weekend and holidays dates missing, so not sequential dates.

I seem to be able to show the change with a query like this

```
SELECT pd.name_id,
   pd.class_id,
   pd.currency, 
   pd.date,
   pd.value,
   ROUND(pd.nav - (SELECT nav
              FROM price_data as x
              WHERE x.date       < pd.date
              AND x.name_id      = pd.name_id
              AND x.class_id     = pd.class_id
              AND x.currency     = pd.currency 
              ORDER BY price_date DESC
              LIMIT 1),5) as change
FROM price_data as pd
```

I've tried to modify that to do an update, but i keep getting a mysql error that says `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'pd' for update in FROM clause` and even then I'm not sure this is the right approach. Would it be easier to do using php?

```
UPDATE price_data as pd
SET pd.change = (
   pd.value - (SELECT value
              FROM price_data as x
              WHERE x.date       < pd.date
              AND x.fund_id      = pd.fund_id
              AND x.class_id     = pd.class_id
              AND x.currency     = pd.currency )
)
```

Thanks for any help you might offer.

Comment: You might use [`CURSORS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) with loops, but in stored procedures. It is one of the ways to handle such things.

Comment: Provide the table structure plz

Comment: What do you need beyond the structure posted at the top of the question?

Comment: @jim CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO (maybe, in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/), so I could reproduce your tables on my system and answer the question properly.

Comment: i hope i did this right - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c69c4

Comment: @jim Your question SQL doesn't match the fiddle -there is no nav field, for example. Plz, correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is not an easy one. So, I decided to split it into 2 requests: 1 SELECT and 1 UPDATE.

The code is made in php and based upon data, you provided in the fiddle:

```
<?php
try {
      $username = 'user';
      $password = '';
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $stmt = $conn->prepare('
SELECT pd.id,
   ROUND(pd.value - (SELECT value
              FROM price_data as x
              WHERE x.price_date       < pd.price_date
              AND x.fund_id      = pd.fund_id
              AND x.class_id     = pd.class_id
              AND x.currency_id     = pd.currency_id
ORDER BY x.price_date DESC
LIMIT 1
),5) as `change`
FROM price_data as pd
WHERE
    pd.`value_change`=0
');
      $stmt->execute();

      $result = array();
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if (!is_null($row["change"]))
            {
                  var_dump($row);
                  $stmt2 = $conn->prepare('
UPDATE
    price_data
SET
    price_data.value_change=:change
WHERE
    price_data.id=:id
');
                  $stmt2->execute($row);
            }
      }


} catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This updated the necessary records on my machine. Let me know, how it worked on yours.

Comment: This worked great on small subsets, thank you so much. I haven't been able to get it to run completely on 400k rows.  I'm trying to just generate the query for the big database at the moment and see if I can just run that - or I'm going to a more powerful machine to try it.

Comment: @jim unfortunately, the SELECT request is taking a lot of resources. But searching maximum, that is less, then the current value is tricky. Maybe, indexing price_date will help.

Comment: Just a note the `HAVING MAX(x.price_date)` seems to cause some odd errors in the calculation, changed it back to `ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1` - you can see the errors starting around `row 6` at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b50a4

Answer (score 0):

**To update date column to one day previous**

```
update table set datefield = date_sub(datefield, interval 1 day)
```